# Accessing an object inside of an array inside an object of arrays

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend

so I have an object of arrays, each array contains a certain object,
now what I wanna do is when I click on any of those objects to be able to select it so I can preview it in VueJs

here's my object:

```
shopitems:{
    pizza:[
      {

        "id": 1,
        "name": "id labore ex et quam laborum",
        "email": "Eliseo@gardner.biz",
        "body": "Margherita",
        "img" : " https://media.onebite.app/62/b2/c5/f7/62b2c5f7-a995-47a6-af1b-64d892692386.jpg",
        "brand" : "pizza",
        "price": "12",
      },
      {

        "id": 2,
        "name": "odio adipisci rerum aut animi",
        "body": "Fresh Veggie",
        "img" : "https://res-2.cloudinary.com/crunchbase-production/image/upload/c_lpad,h_256,w_256,f_auto,q_auto:eco/r6krxkmxkkthsbw9fm9f",
        "brand" : "pizza",
        "price": "30",
      },
     
    ],
    salad:[
      {

        "id":3,
        "name": "id labore ex et quam laborum",
        "email": "Eliseo@gardner.biz",
        "body": "Salad u",
        "img" : "https://nitrocdn.com/KZJKWDkEwMJCwERIlnRsPNdqobwBIlEo/assets/static/optimized/rev-83d0269/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/brazilian-chopped-salad-10-256x256.jpg",
        "brand" : "salad",
        "price": "12",
      },
      {

        "id": 4,
        "name": "odio adipisci rerum aut animi",
        "body": "Salad V",
        "img" : "https://bigoven-res.cloudinary.com/image/upload/d_recipe-no-image.jpg,t_recipe-256/mixed-greens-salad-with-tomato-443eb4.jpg",
        "brand" : "salad",
        "price": "25",     
      },
      
    ],
    
  },
```

this is my function that I tried to use

```
        this.$store.state.eCommerce.shopitems.find((items) =>
         items.forEach((item) => item.id = id))
          return  this.item_data = this.item
```

please kindly tell me what am I doing wrong

Comment: share a valid json.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to access/modify pizza array, you are accessing wrong object

```
this.$store.state.eCommerce.shopitems.pizza.find((items) =>
         items.forEach((item) => item.id = id))
          return  this.item_data = this.item
```

Answer (score 0):

shopitems is an object not array so you can't use .find().
you can do like this
initialize empty array and then add  shopitems  to this array and use find function

```
`var myArray = []
   myArray.push( this.$store.state.eCommerce.shopitems)
   myArray.find((items) =>
    items.forEach((item) => item.id = id))return  this.item_data = this.item
this.$store.state.eCommerce.shopitems = myArray[0] ? myArray[0] : {}`
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be a good idea to transform your object to an array. There are multiple ways to achieve that.

```
let objectKeys=Object.keys(yourObject);
let yourObjectArray=[];

objectKeys.forEach(x=>{
      yourObjectArray.push(yourObject[x])
 });
```

Or maybe

let yourObjectArray=[...yourObject]

Once you got the array,  you can use filter() as usual